# Creating json list of lists from dataframe

Tags: r, json, dataframe

Very new to R, I have a data.frame of mixed types and need to convert it to a json object that has each row of the data.frame as a list within a list, with the column headers as the first list.

Closest I've come is the below,

```
library(jsonlite)
df <- data.frame(X=as.numeric(c(1,2,3)),
                 Y=as.numeric(c(4,5,6)),
                 Z=c('a', 'b', 'c'),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
test <- split(unname(df), 1:NROW(df))
toJSON(test)
```

Which gives,

```
{"1":[[1,4,"a"]],"2":[[2,5,"b"]],"3":[[3,6,"c"]]}
```

If there's some way to remove the keys and flatten the value list by one level I could make this work by adding the colnames, but is there an easier way I'm missing? Output I'd like is,

```
{[["X","Y","Z"],[1,4,"a"],[2,5,"b"],[3,6,"c"]]}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea is to get the json format you want your data needs to be in a list of vectors (2D Vectors and 2D lists do not work).

Hey here is one way, there is probably a more elegant one but this works (but it makes the numbers strings, I can't find away around that sorry).

```
library(rlist)

df <- data.frame(X=as.numeric(c(1,2,3)),
                 Y=as.numeric(c(4,5,6)),
                 Z=c('a', 'b', 'c'),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#make the column names a row and then remove them
names <- colnames(df)
df[2:nrow(df)+1,] <- df
df[1,] <- names
colnames(df) <- NULL

#convert the df into a list containing vectors
data <- list()
for(i in seq(1,nrow(df))){
  data <- list.append(data,as.vector(df[i,]))
}

toJSON(data)
```